# Get object with variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have in database and in one entity two properties:

```
title_one
title_two
```

And in template (TWIG) i would like get only one from these fields.

```
{% set type = 'two' %}
```

I can:

```
<div id="title">
{% if type == 'one' %}
    {% entity.title_one %}
{% elseif type == 'two' %}
    {% entity.title_two %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

It works well, but I'd like to do something like this:

```
<div id="title">
    {{ entity.title_{{ type }} }}
</div>
```

How can i make it?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear: Are `title_one` and `title_two` separate entities, or are they properties of the same entity?

Comment: Sorry, they are properties of the same entity.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the [Twig attribute function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) like this :

```
{{ attribute(entity, "title_" ~ type) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a helper method to the entity, something like `getMyType()`. This would return the proper type. In the the Twig template, you can access this method:

```twig
{% set type == myEntity.getMyType() %}
```

Note that you have to inject the entity into the template in your controller:

```php
$Response = $this->render(
    "MySomethingBundle:Area:page.html.twig",
    array('myEntity' => $entityInstance));
```

By the way, you might want to have a look at [different strategies of inheritance mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).